# MOSS 2007 Search Scope  Items "not available"

Tags: search-scope

Search is working for my first site collection. Then I did backup/restore and the new site collection search is not working. I checked teh crawl and its crawling, however in the Search Scope items it says "not available"

What is the issue?

Comment: Basically i have an error in creating Score Rule: it says "Total:Error"

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the rules in your scopes? If you have multiple rules then there may be some of the rules may not be properly evaluated. It can happen due to changes in managed property type (column changed from Text to number etc.).

Try to remove rules one by one, and compile the scope each time, to find the erroneous rule.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue usually occurs due to irregular reboot of the server.

For instance, during your full crawl the server can be rebooted or shut down for few min/hour. If so, the full crawl will be inactive and the corresponding timer will be restarted automatically. once the server is up. So the crawl will result as error. Stating while crawling,it cannot communicate with server. Check the availability of server.

Resolution : Do incremental crawling to fix the issue. while incremental crawling will take few hours/min. depend on the your storage.